# GridLayoutManager ViewHolder gravity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager that has a spanCount of 2. The ViewHolder is for a vertical LinearLayout with an ImageView and a TextView. The LinearLayout has a setSize, say 100dp by 100dp. When I am viewing my Activity in Landscape mode, I want each cell in the grid to be centered within its span. But instead, each is left-justified. So again, because I have a span of 2 and each View occupies a span of 1, then I have two views per row. I want each row to be centered within its span as opposed to being left-justified. How do I do that?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new grid_item.xml that fits the grid layout and rearrange all your views accordingly within. 
you can than define a boolean variable in your adapter class, according to which you will decide which list/grid item to inflate inside onCreateViewHolder.

```
     public DataHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                if (isGrid){
                   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item , parent ,false);
                }else{
                   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item , parent ,false);
                }
                return new DataHolder(view);
   }
```

good luck